# pyodbc is present in showing "No module name pyodbc"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to connect my python code to sql server. But there is an error which shows:
import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                  "Server=localhost;"
                  "Database=SCMS2;"
                  "uid=sa;pwd=tazbirul94")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Suppliers')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Here is the pip freeze command:
[image]

This shows my odbc is present:
[image]
Here is the error
[image]
[Here is my pycharm environment path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kffhI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pycharm is using a python from a `.../venv/...` folder while what you type in the cmd does not. Make sure to use the same python version for both.

One way would be to go to:

File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter and change to the python that you have installed the module for

Comment: i have tried your solution but my interpreter is already same as my python version. Still getting the same error while running the code

Comment: Can you confirm that you now `...\appdata\local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe` Is displayed at the top of the Pycharm console output when you run your script?

Comment: i have added the environment setting image to the question. I am totally new on python but my base interpreter is showing the location given by you before. thank you

Comment: Change from the "Virtual Environment" to "System Interpreter", make sure that your python36 one is selected there and hit apply

Comment: thank you for your advice. I am really grateful to you